# Error in creating or updating view from existing table

Tags: oracle, view

I tried to create a view in oracle but it shows

```
 "table or view does not exist"
```

Query :

```
create or replace view schema1.view1 as select x.id,x.name,y.address from person x, details y where x.id=y.id;
```

This select query working fine `select x.id,x.name,y.address from person x, details y where x.id=y.id;`

but can't create view with that

Comment: You log in with the account SCHEMA1 and the query runs fine, but when you want to create the view in the same schema this fails? Or do you log in with a different account?

Comment: The most likely explanation given the limited facts you have presented is that your `person` and `details` tables are a part of some schema other than `schema1` and `schema1` doesn't have the correct permissions to view them. Depending on the version of Oracle you are using, permissions granted through a role will work for direct SQL commands, but will *not* work for PL/SQL objects like views. In order to reference those objects inside of other objects, the permissions on each source object must be granted directly and not inherited through roles. Talk to your DBA to get the permissions right.